# What is the philosophy of Yatharth Geeta?

Tags: bhagavad-gita

[Yatharth Geeta](https://www.yatharthgeeta.com/) is the most popular for its translation available in almost all global languages. It is freely distributed both in soft copy and hard copy.

Swami Adgadananda who translated this Geeta claims to have been translated as Bhagavad Geeta was meant to be. This is not something new and even ISKCON claims it's 'Bhagavada Gita As It Is' to be most authentic of all.

But my question is about the philosophy of Yatharth Geeta. The author says that it doesn't matter if Krishna existed or if Mahabharata ever happened and connects various characters of Mahabharata to metaphorical. Like Drona to double conduct, Krishna to Guru etc. What's even more surprising to me is how worship of deities is shown to be wrong(even Krishna) and the belief in One God without form is promoted.

So my question is what is the philosophy of this widely distributed Yatharth Geeta? Is it a Vedantic commentary?

Answer (score 0):

What bhagavad gita tells us to do? Ans- Karma.

What is karma? Ans- Yajna/Yagya. (BG 3/9)

Which is better form of Yajna/Yagya? Ans- Jap Yagya or Name Chanting (BG 10/25)

Everywhere in Yatharth Gita you will read Rāma name.
Yatharth Gita, Tulsidas's Ramcharitmanas and Vinay Patrika, Kabir das, Guru Gobind and everyone says to chant particular name " Rāma ".

Yajna/Yagya is falsely translated as Sacrifice. It can be translated as Prayer, handclasp. It is वंदना in simple hindi.